# Does Access 2013 still have an ACE database or equivalent?

Tags: ms-access, ms-office, ms-jet-ace, office-2013

Does Access 2013 require the use of a separate database (such as SQL Server), or does it include the ACE database or an equivalent, that is bundled in the file?

Answer (score 3):

The successor to JET now called ACE is included. This version of the data engine continues to support and read mdb, or accDB files.

It is file based and I have converted say Access 2000 databases without issue.

The ACE database includes the DAO reference by default.

So no change, and even Access 97 applications should run just fine in 2013.

Note that the ACE data engine included does now have table triggers and store procedures. It also can now link tables to SQL Azure (cloud) edition of SQL server.

However, really no change in the last 20 years – it still runs and feels and looks like JET, and no server of any kind is required.

So you are essentially still using the DAO object model, and it continues to be the preferred choice when using Access.

So no server required, and it works the same as it has for the last 20 years.

Comment: Thanks.  That's good to hear.  The online information I was able to find also said you can't define your own tables and fields.  It said you have to select a template and then Access gives you an out of the box dataset.  Can you also debunk that one because that scares me.

Comment: I don't know where you read as such, but there really no change in the last 20 years of that product in regards to using the simple table design mode. So once again, there no feature in the basic product that changed in the last 20 years. So creating forms, writing VBA code – it is all quite much the same as before. So I not sure what you been reading, but all is well and normal in Access land.

Comment: Actually, Access 97 databases are not supported in 2013: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/discontinued-features-and-modified-functionality-in-access-2013-HA102749226.aspx

Answer (score 0):

According to [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Access#Versions), it still includes a Jet database (Jet version 15).